# Disable SSL/TLS renegotiation in Apache CXF client

Tags: java, security, ssl, cxf, jsse

I am using Apache CXF libraries to connect to a webserver which does not allow SSL/TLS renegotiation. But, my client tries to perform renegotiation every time resulting in an error on the server-side.

Is there a way to completely disable SSL/TLS renegotiation on the Apache CXF client?

Comment: Have you tried to add -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true to your VM parameters of your client program?

Comment: Have you tried loading the certificate into your JDK?